# Firebase retrieving arrays

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider a document has 2 arrays namely "studentIds" and "studentNames".
so I want to retrieve a single array using:

```
documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

arrList = (ArrayList) documentSnapshot.get("studentIds");

}
```

Now what I would like to know is does doing this make it retrieve the whole document i.e both the arrays . or just the array I specify?
Does it affect my performance?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you read a document using one of the web or mobile client SDKs, the entire contents of the document are transferred to the client.  There is no way to avoid this.  If you don't want to read the entire contents of the document, split the fields into multiple documents and read them individually.